# Whats the reason for 'bad value for restricted picklist field:' error?

Tags: workflow, case

I am getting the below error on saving the WF rule:
There were custom validation error(s) encountered while saving the affected record(s). The first validation error encountered was

> "Dependent Entity: bad value for restricted picklist field:
>   EmailMessage".

`

```
AND(if(Incoming = true,true,false),
    if(isclosed = true,true,false),
    OR(if(parent.Recordtype.Name = 'xyz',true,false))
```

Comment: Did you mean "INCOMING AND (CLOSED OR RECORDTYPE="XYZ")", or did you mean "INCOMING AND CLOSED AND RECORDTYPE="XYZ"? It's not clear from the way you wrote your formula (but, for the record, it currently operates as INCOMING AND CLOSED AND RECORDTYPE="XYZ").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Parent.RecordType.Name` is not supported, as far as I can tell. Instead, it appears you have to filter by record type ID. I was able to make a rule that would work:

```
AND(INCOMING, PARENT.ISCLOSED, PARENT.RECORDTYPEID='0123000000000000')
```

Admittedly, this isn't a best practice, so you should probably instead use standard filters:

```
(Email Message: Is Incoming EQUALS True) AND (Case: Closed EQUALS True) AND (Case: Case Record Type EQUALS ABC)
```

Comment: I am currently using the standard filters,but we want to bypass this rule for few profiles so we are using a custom setting. I am not able to add the custom setting in the standard filter.

Comment: That makes sense. In that case, did the parent.recordtypeid method work?

Comment: I was already using the above approach but its not the best approach. Any how it works thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is suggested at https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000SzitAAC :

Create a formula on the object to fetch the record type name, and use that formula. That workaround worked for me.